# protractor: for each element, scrape title, price e.t.c

Tags: protractor

as practice, I am writing some scripts to scrape product info from amazon.com.au

I am able to return all the results elements. My plan is to scrape title from each result. If I can get the title, then I can check if price is present.

I find some products don't have the price.

steps:
navigate to amazon.com.au
select book, enter lion king classic collection, click search

the following is my code snippet:

```
  it('search for book', async function() {
    
    var $res = '//div[contains(@class,"sg-col-0-of-12 sg-col-16-of-20")]'
    
    var $T = '//span[@class="a-size-medium a-color-base a-text-normal"]'
    
    var $result = element.all(by.xpath($res))

    var $count = await $result.count() 
    
    for(var $i =0;$i<$count;$i++)
    {
    
        $txt = await $result.get($i).element(element(by.xpath($T)).locator()).getText()
        console.log("title: "+$i+" "+$txt)
    }
```

I would be most grateful if anyone can provide some pointers.
this the output I'm getting, lots of duplicates:

```
title: 18 Disney: The Lion King Classic Collection
[17:35:36] W/element - more than one element found for locator By(xpath, //span[
@class="a-size-medium a-color-base a-text-normal"]) - the first result will be u
sed
title: 19 Disney: The Lion King Classic Collection
[17:35:36] W/element - more than one element found for locator By(xpath, //span[
@class="a-size-medium a-color-base a-text-normal"]) - the first result will be u
sed
title: 20 Disney: The Lion King Classic Collection
[17:35:36] W/element - more than one element found for locator By(xpath, //span[
@class="a-size-medium a-color-base a-text-normal"]) - the first result will be u
sed
```

Answer (score 1):

Recommend to use CSS locator, but XPATH.

```
// all books in search result
book_rows = element.all(by.css('span[data-component-type="s-search-results"] div[data-component-type="s-search-result"]'))

books = book_rows.map(function(it){
    // find title web element inside each result row
    title_ele = it.element(by.css('.s-title-instructions-style > h2'))

    // price web element inside each result row
    price_ele = it.element(by.css('.s-price-instructions-style .a-price'))

    // check title and price web element presents
    existence = await Promise.all([title_ele.isPresnt(), price_ele.isPresnt()])

    return {
        'title': existence[0] && await title_ele.getText() || 'title not found',
        'price': existence[1] && await price_ele.getText() || 'price not found'
    }
})
```

Comment: Thanks! I was experimenting today and I realised using xpath in the child was a blocker, yes I used css and now it's working. I like your code. Thanks for your response, I will try it out and see how that goes.

Comment: you need to prefix `.` in xpath in child, like `var $T = './/span[@class="a-size-medium a-color-base a-text-normal"]'`,  without the heading `.` , xpath find element from root node of page, with `.` , xpath find element from context node.  CSS is more efficient on finding element  than XPATH and better supported by main browsers.

Comment: yea, I think that's the problem. I have been used to just using ```//``` and didn't think of adding ```.```